# JavaFX: CSS Dropdown Menu not Appearing In Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, css, user-interface, drop-down-menu, javafx-2

I've been following the tutorials on the Oracle website for JavaFX, and I've started using CSS for the styles and rules of the GUI. One thing that I've been running into lately is that while using the CSS editor in Netbeans there does not appear to be a dropdown list of possible properties to change (by using ctrl + space). I use the ctrl + space for just about everything in mainline Java programming, and I'm kind of missing it for the CSS editor, is there any way I could get this type of functionality from the CSS editor?

Comment: What version of netbeans are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 7.4.

Comment: Mine works in 7.4, maybe check your plugins.  I have 2 installed with css in the name, CSS Source Model & CSS Preprocessors

Comment: I would suggest you perform one more clean installation. All css auto completes work on my 7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete for JavaFX CSS works for me in NetBeans.

*Screenshot*

[image: netbeanscompletion]

The screenshot was made using NetBeans 7.4 and editing a CSS file in a NetBeans JavaFX project.  The auto-complete pop-ups were brought up by typing `-fx`, then pressing <kbd>CTRL + SPACE</kbd>.

*Errata*

You will notice the weird `No documentation found` text, which is related to [NetBeans feature request 215171](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=215171) (which hasn't been implemented in NetBeans 7.4).  This means that the auto-complete works, it just doesn't provide any supporting context sensitive reference documentation on what the CSS means - to determine that you will need to manually look-up the information in the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

*Caveat*

The auto-complete for JavaFX CSS only works for a JavaFX project type, if you create a NetBeans Java Application project rather than a JavaFX Application project, then the autocomplete will just autocomplete regular HTML CSS attributes rather than JavaFX CSS Attributes, as you can see by the screenshot below which attempts an autocomplete on the same css file copied into a regular Java project.

[image: netbeanscompletionfail]

Comment: Wow! Nice catch! So I should have a dummy JavaFX project for writing the CSS and transfer it over when I want to run it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that Sarah.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend switching IDEs.  **Eclipse** has a similar feature.  It has a plugin called **[e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)**

[image]

Comment: [Intellij Idea 13](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) also has this auto-complete feature for JavaFX CSS, though I believe it's only in the Ultimate Edition, not the Community Edition.

Comment: @jewelsea I was actually going to mention Intellij as well, but good version isn't free.  |=^[